# Invalid indentation in Jade

Tags: jade4j

I'm getting below error while trying to insert a script file in `Jade`

Can anyone please help?

```
 form(method='post', action='/posts/add', enctype="mutilpart/form-data")
    .form-group
        label Title:
        input.form-control(name='title', type='text')
   .form-group
        label Category:
        select.form-control(name='category')
            each category, i in categories
                option(value='#{category.title}') #{category.title}
    .form-group
        label Body:
        textarea.form-control(name='body', id='body')
    .form-group
        label Main Image:
        input.form-control(name='mainimage', type='file')
    .form-group
        label Author:
        select.form-control(anme='author')
            option(value='Brad Traversy') Brad Traversy
            option(value='John Doe') John Doe
    input.btn.btn-defalut(name='submit',type='submit',value='Save')
    script(src='/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')
    script
        | CKEDITOR.replace('body');
```

Comment: Please find the error below .. > 30| script(src='/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') 31| script 32| | CKEDITOR.replace('body'); 33| Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both
Error: C:\Users\Mohan Kala\Desktop\NodeProjects\nodeblog\views\addpost.jade:30
    28|                 option(value='John Doe') John Doe
    29|         input.btn.btn-defalut(name='submit',type='submit',value='Save')
  > 30|      script(src='/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')
    31|      script
    32|       | CKEDITOR.replace('body');
    33|   
Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both

Comment: please edit your question and add the error.

Comment: improved title and question

Answer (score 0):

You have an syntax error here. Replace

```
    script
     CKEDITOR.replace('body');
```

by

```
    script.
     CKEDITOR.replace('body');
```